# Register and login buttons are not appearing Bootstrap Navbar

Tags: navbar, laravel-5.4, bootstrap-4, laravel-blade

I have implemented some code into my Navbar so that a user can login or register into the site.  The problem I am having is that the buttons are not appearing.  Below is my code.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-xl navbar-inverse bg-primary">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Home</a>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Speakers</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Schedule</a>
                </li>
                @if(Auth::check())
                <li role="presentation" class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"
                  role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> Hello {{Auth::user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span> </a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="{{ route('jobs.index') }}">Jobs</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{{ route('sectors.index') }}">Sectors</a></li>
                   <li><a href="{{ route('statuses.index') }}">Status</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/jobs/create">Create a Job</a></li>
                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="{{ route('logout')}}">Logout</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>

              @else
              <a href="{{ route('login') }}" class="btn btn-default">Login</a>
              <a href="{{ route('register') }}" class="btn btn-default">Register</a>
            @endif
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Also I want to move the login and register buttons to the right of the Navbar.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have probably logged in before and used the remember me button, try clearing your cache and refresh the page. to move the buttons to the right you can just use css styling

wrap the buttons in a div tag and float it to the right

```
<div style="right: 0; position: absolute;">
   <a href="{{ route('login') }}" class="btn btn-success">Login</a>
   <a href="{{ route('register') }}" class="btn btn-danger">Register</a></div>
```

Comment: That did not fix it DarkseidNG.  It's still the same.

Comment: Can you post the entire code so i can review it properly

Comment: Where can I post it?

Comment: post it as a comment

Comment: I will try but I think there is a limit to the number of characters.  All the code for the Navbar is above.

Comment: Cool, that seemed to move it to the right. The login button is green but the Register button is still the same colour as the Navbar.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: The buttons are being displayed but their color is the same as the background color of the navbar. just change the color of the text or use a colored bootstrap button, then for the float use absolute position and set right to 0. but it still retains some of the padding from your navbar. I have edited my answer, see the corrections there. Dont forget to upvote the answer